# Telnet port 587

Tags: networking, email, port, iis, smtp

Our IIS hosted system sends Email through an account `example@ieu-iq.org`. Sometime ago, my ISP blocked port 25 so it stopped sending, talking to my email provider **GoDaddy**, they said I can use port 587. When I try to telnet from any machine on my local network, I get Could not open

```
telnet ieu-iq.org 587
Connecting To smtp.ieu-iq.org...Could not open connection to the host, on port 587: Connect failed
```

Maybe the port is also blocked by my ISP or my Router/Firewall, but when I talked to them, they said it's opened. Also, I tried this:

```
telnet smtp.office365.com 587
220 AM0PR02CA0090.outlook.office365.com Microsoft ESMTP MAIL Service ready at Sun, 30 May 2021 15:32:58 +0000
```

That might mean the issue is with my domain/email provider, so I tried from a cloud server(outside of my network), the telnet succeded.

I'm confused, what is the issue here.
 Also, I couldn't determine, is IIS considered a **mail server** or a **mail client**?

Appreciate you help.

Comment: To be able to connect to the mail server (yes, you’re the client here) at port 587, it needs to be listening on this port. While it is commonly configured like this, this is in no way guaranteed. Contact the mail server operator for `ieu-iq.org` to get more information. Or is that operator GoDaddy? // I also see that you are connecting to `ieu-iq.org`, not a specific mail server. Are you positive this is correct?

Comment: As an FYI, [according to MXToolbox](https://mxtoolbox.com/SuperTool.aspx?action=mx%3aieu-iq.org&run=toolpage), the mail host for `ieu-iq.org` is given as `mail.ieu-iq.org`. And connecting via Telnet to `mail.ieu-iq.org:587` currently seems to fetch a `service ready` (220) response from [Exim](https://www.exim.org/).

Answer (score 2):

Seems like GoDaddy is at fault here, and port 587 is likely blocked, not properly configured or there's something else preventing you from connecting.

Port 465 is another port you can try.

If that doesn't work either, contact GoDaddy Support again and tell them its not working. Send them your connection attempt as you posted here including the office365 one so they know its not on your end, but on theirs.

It is also possible that the port itself is open, but you were temporarily banned for too many incorrect connection attempts.